# this method must return a result of type boolean

Tags: java

i am rewriting class string in java but for some method like startwith i have the same error. this is my code:

```
public boolean mystartwith(MyString s){
    if(s.mylength() > this.mylength()){
    return false;
    }else{
    for(int i=0 ; i<s.mylength() ; i++){
        if(lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
            return false;
        }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i have this error :  "this method must return a result of type boolean"

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop when you always return either false or true on the first iteration? `i` can never be anything else than zero.

Comment: The compiler can't see what you will return after the for loop finishes. BTW, your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `s` is empty, `for` loop will be skipped - and your method won't return anything at all, hence the error. I'd rather add checking for this condition first.

Have to note, though, that given algorithm is flawed:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.mylength() ; i++){
  if (lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Ok, let's say I called this function with 'abc' string given as `s`, but instance wraps over the string 'acdef'. Guess what, your method will return `true`! The problem is that your loop breaks too soon: a value is returned right after checking for the first letter.

Actually, it should be written like this:

```
int sLength = s.myLength();
if (sLength == 0) {
  return false; 
  // actually, it's for you to decide: 
  // technically each string begins with an empty string
}
if (sLength > this.mylength()) {
  return false;
}
for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
  if (lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

The key difference: `true` is returned *only* if `for` loop is walked over normally (i.e., exited via `i < sLength` condition. That, in turn, means, that all the characters of `s` string match those at the beginning of the string wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `if(s.mylength() > this.mylength())` is not satisfied, then your code will go to the loop. 
Now suppose the `for` loop doesn't loop, meaning `s` is empty. What will be returned?

Exactly! Nothing, since the loop will be skipped. 
To fix this, you should `return` some `boolean` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s.mylength() > this.mylength()){
    return false;
}else{
    for(int i=0 ; i<s.mylength() ; i++){
        if(lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
            return false;
        }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
    return ____; //place true or false based on your condition
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun how it is? :)

Comment: Now it won't compile because of `____`.. :D

Comment: just fill that blank with true or flase! :)

Answer (score 0):

Java must guarantee that a boolean will be returned whatever the input, however there are conditions in which there is no return

```
public boolean mystartwith(MyString s){
    if(s.mylength() > this.mylength()){
        return false;
    }else{
        for(int i=0 ; i<s.mylength() ; i++){
            if(lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        //what if s.mylength()==0 and the loop never runs?!
        //therefore the code will get to here, and the method will end without a return
    }
}
```

Note that java isn't "clever enough" to recognise that two ifs together make all posibilities. For example

```
  boolean method(int a){
    if (a>0){
        return true;
    }else{

       if (a<=0){
          return false;
       }
       //program can never get here, BUT java doesn't realise that
  }
```

Still doesn't satisfy java because it imagines a scenario where both ifs are false

How to fix this depends on your specific program, but it's worth noting that the for loop will only run once at most before returning so is superfluos

Answer (score 0):

You can to redefine your code like this:

```
public boolean mystartwith(MyString s){
    if(s.mylength() > this.mylength()){
       return false;
    }else{
       for(int i=0 ; i<s.mylength() ; i++){
          if(lesCaracteres[i] != s.lesCaracteres[i]){
             return false;
          }else{
             return true;
          }
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```